# Renovate: multiple 'allowedVersions' settings for the same package pattern

Tags: renovate

Our company-preset-repo `default.json` contains the following `packageRule` which is supposed to exclude maven dependencies that contain `.redhat-` in the `<version>` field.

```
{
  "matchManagers": ["maven"],
  "matchPackageNames": [
    "commons-io:commons-io",
    "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3",
    "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient",
    "com.cronutils:cron-utils",
    "com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path",
    "com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream",
    "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api",
    "net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple",
    "org.jsoup:jsoup",
    "org.yaml:snakeyaml"
  ],
  "allowedVersions": "!/\\.redhat-/"
}
```

In my own team, I created my own renovate preset `default.json` file which `extends` `local>company-preset-repo` and that looks something like this, with the aim of preventing renovate from replacing e.g. `commons-io` version `2.11.0` with version `20030203.000550`:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "description": [
    "Default preset for my team"
  ],
  "gitAuthor": "some@email",
  "extends": [
    "local>company-preset-repo"
  ],
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchPackagePatterns": [
        "^org.apache.commons:",
        "^commons-beanutils:",
        "^commons-cli:",
        "^commons-collections:",
        "^commons-io:"
      ],
      "allowedVersions": "/^\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{1,2}(\\..*)?$/"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's my problem:

I'm getting renovate pull-requests for `commons-io` version `2.11.0.redhat-00001`. I want both the first pattern to apply AND the second pattern to apply. In other words, I only want renovate to suggest dependency updates for `commons-io` when both of these patterns apply:

1. The version isn't something like `20030203.000550`
2. AND: The version doesn't contain `.redhat-`

Can this be done, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

In the end we solved it with a Regex which combines both patterns into one single pattern. So for those few packages in my own rule it is this more complex pattern that is applied instead of the more simple one from `company-preset-repo`.

```
"allowedVersions": "/^(\\d{1,3}\\.)(\\d*\\.)*\\d*(?!.*\\.redhat-.*)$/"
```